# Can XSD validate inter-field dependencies?

Tags: xsd

I'm looking for a way for my XSD file to validate one field based on the content of another.
For example, it may need to validate that my "start date" field is before my "end date" field.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, you can't do it with what you refer to "XSD" and probably means W3C XML Schema 1.0

Long answer:
You CAN validate such things with RelaxNG + Schematron or if it has to be XSD, use W3C schema 1.1 with it's assertion mechanism. Version 1.1 is currently in a Candidate Release phase so not a full recommendation, so you tools probably don't support that yet.
On a more philosophical level, you might want to consider whether weaving such fine-grained business rules is a right approach. I am currently involved in several standards and in those standards, I make sure it's the end user application that validates such business rules - it's too broad for a standard schema to define things in such detail, the schema would be too big, verbose, have a too steep learning curve and be much harder to maintain.